# Free alternative to DB2 for localhost development

Tags: database, db2

I am looking for free DBMS options for a localhost environment, which will support migrating data and database objects (e.g. stored procedures, table definitions) to a DB2 9.5 installation.  We can't use DB2 in localhost due to cost/licensing constraints, but would benefit from each developer having his/her own database to use locally.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use the [free Express edition](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/)?